# Help with a ForEach: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, html

Quiero obtener de mi base de datos el nombre de mis proyectos por sus ids. Sin embargo, forEach me da un argumento inválido para foreach(). Espero que me puedan ayudar, Gracias de antemano

Consulta:

```
function obtenerNombreProyecto($id){
include 'conexion.php';
try{
  
  return mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT nombre FROM proyectos WHERE id = $id");
} catch(Exception $e){
    echo "Error! : ". getMessage($e);
    return false;
}
```

}

Guardando el id en su variable correspondiente

```
if (isset($_GET['id_proyecto'])) {
    $id_proyecto=$_GET['id_proyecto'];
```

LLamando a la funcion y pasandole el id

```
<?php 
        $proyecto=obtenerNombreProyecto($id_proyecto);


         if ($proyecto): ?>           

     
        <h1> Proyecto Actual:
            <?php foreach ($proyecto as $nombre): ?>
            <span><?php echo $nombre['nombre']; ?></span>
            <?php endforeach ?>
        </h1>

        <form action="#" class="agregar-tarea">
            <div class="campo">
                <label for="tarea">Tarea:</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre Tarea" class="nombre-tarea"> 
            </div>
            <div class="campo enviar">
                <input type="hidden" id="<?php echo $id_proyecto; ?>" value="id_proyecto">
                <input type="submit" class="boton nueva-tarea" value="Agregar">
            </div>
        </form>
        
        <?php 
            else:
                //Si no hay proyectos seleccionado
                echo "<p>Selecciona un Proyecto a la izquierda</p>";
            endif;

         ?>
```

Comment: prueba impimir en pantalla  la variable `$proyecto`   de la siguiente manera `var_dump( $proyecto);`  y agrega el resultado en la pregunta  para ver la estructura.

Comment: Imprime bool false

Comment: Puedes agrrgar el codigo del documento `conexion.php`  concretamente el constructor si es una `clase`

Comment: <?php                      $conexion=new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'uptask');                                      
 if($conexion->conect_error){ echo $conexion->conect_error;}          $conexion->set_charset('uft8');

Comment: agregalo al post editandolo .... no en los comentarios es informacion importante todo apunta a que tu query/conexion o algo esta mal...